# How do i choose which url should be print?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

im working with this api Tenor (im using python with requests and json libs), which bassically send gifs url's with parameters like size and format (in a json file). The problem is that it sends me a lot of gifs, and i want to choose the ones where width > heigh in the dimensions of the file. This dimensions are in the json data as "dims", so i want to print the url just in case this condition exists, but if not, i still want a response (if the condition doesn't exist, search again and again...). I will post the json archive if anybody can help me, i would appreciate it so much :(

here is the json file which sends 10 gifs with each parameters:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/190Ua6DA1vVeG5j002noXhRVOcBY6QWzK/view?usp=sharing

(results - (int for random gif choose) - media_formats - gif - dims)

Comment: please post the relevant json data as text in your question (no external link). What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should use the [Endpoint's Parameters](https://developers.google.com/tenor/guides/endpoints#search), is `ar_range=wide` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does the job you need (if I got it):

```
with open('gifs.json', 'r') as f:
    json_content = json.load(f)
    for result in json_content['results']:
        w, h = result['media_formats']['gif']['dims']
        if w > h:
            print(result['content_description'].ljust(25), result['itemurl'])
            for media_k, media_v in result['media_formats'].items():
                print('\t', media_k.ljust(30), media_v['url'])
        print()
```

of course, change

```
with open('gifs.json', 'r') as f:
    json_content = json.load(f)
```

by

```
json_content = json.loads(str_content)
```

if you already have the content as string.

A few lines from the output:

```
Anime Hug GIF             https://tenor.com/view/anime-hug-sweet-love-gif-14246498
     tinywebm                       https://c.tenor.com/9e1aE_xBLCsAAAP3/anime-hug.webm
     tinygif                        https://c.tenor.com/9e1aE_xBLCsAAAAM/anime-hug.gif
     loopedmp4                      https://c.tenor.com/9e1aE_xBLCsAAAPo/anime-hug.mp4
     gifpreview                     https://c.tenor.com/9e1aE_xBLCsAAAAe/anime-hug.png
     [...]

Anime Hug Love GIF        https://tenor.com/view/anime-hug-love-smile-gif-15942846
     webm                           https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAPs/anime-hug-love.webm
     gifpreview                     https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAAe/anime-hug-love.png
     gif                            https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAAC/anime-hug-love.gif
     tinymp4                        https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAP1/anime-hug-love.mp4
     nanomp4                        https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAP2/anime-hug-love.mp4
     tinygif                        https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAAM/anime-hug-love.gif
     nanogif                        https://c.tenor.com/DVOTqLcB2jUAAAAS/anime-hug-love.gif
     [...]
```